# Can't pass an object from class to another

Tags: c#, xna

The game stopped working when the following function is called:

The error is: shotmanager object wont be passed and always will be null! I was following a tutorial and did exactly as he did!

I clearly initiated it.

Some coding here

```
namespace SpaceShip
{
    class Enemy: Sprite 
    {
        public shotmanager shotmanager;
        private double timesincelastshot;
        private const int timedelay = 1;
        private Vector2 pos;

        public Enemy(Texture2D Text, Vector2 VEC, Rectangle REC, shotmanager shotmanager)
            : base(Text, VEC, REC)
        {
            shipspeed = 300;
            this.shotmanager = shotmanager;
        }

        public override void Update(KeyboardState keyboard, GameTime gameTime)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            if (Velocity == Vector2.Zero)
            {
                var direction = random.Next(2);
                Velocity = new Vector2(direction == 0 ? -1 : 1, 0);
            }
            else if (gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Seconds % 2 == 0)
            {
                if (random.Next(15) == 0)
                    Velocity = new Vector2(-velocity.X, velocity.Y);
            }

            timesincelastshot += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
            if (timesincelastshot > timedelay)
            {
                if (random.Next(2) == 0)
                    pos = calculateposition();
                shotmanager.fireenemyshot(pos);

                timesincelastshot = 0;

            }
            base.Update(keyboard, gameTime);
        }

        private Vector2 calculateposition()
        {
            return VEC + new Vector2(TEXT.Width/2, TEXT.Height/2);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace SpaceShip
{
    public class shotmanager
    {
        private Shot shot;
        public Texture2D shottexture;
        private Rectangle bounds;
        private List<Shot> shotgroup = new List<Shot>();
        //public shooting shot;
        Vector2 vec;

        public shotmanager(Texture2D shottexture, Rectangle bounds)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.shottexture = shottexture;
            this.bounds = bounds;
        }

        public void fireenemyshot(Vector2 shotposition)
        {
            var inflatebounds = bounds;
            vec = shotposition;

            inflatebounds.Inflate(10, 10);
            shot.Velocity = new Vector2(0, 1);

            shotgroup.Add(shot);
            shot = new Shot(shottexture, shotposition, inflatebounds);
        }

        public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            foreach (var i in shotgroup)
                shot.draw(spriteBatch);
        }

        public void Update(KeyboardState keyboard, GameTime gameTime)
        {
            foreach (var i in shotgroup)
                shot.Update(keyboard, gameTime);
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
namespace SpaceShip
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Sprite background;
        shipclass spaceship;
        //Sprite spaceship;
        SpriteFont score;
        EnemyManger enemy;
        Texture2D shottexture;
        public  shotmanager shotmanager;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.

            var alienship = Content.Load<Texture2D>("flying_saucer_2");

            Texture2D spaceshiptexture;
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            spaceshiptexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("1358114942_kspaceduel");
            var positionx = (graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - spaceshiptexture.Width) / 2;
            var positiony = (graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - spaceshiptexture.Height );
            var ship = new Rectangle(0, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - spaceshiptexture.Height -150 , graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, spaceshiptexture.Height+150);
            background = new Sprite(Content.Load<Texture2D>("large_space_1920x1200"), Vector2.Zero, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds);
            spaceship = new shipclass(spaceshiptexture, new Vector2(positionx, positiony), ship);
            score = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("SpriteFont1");
            shottexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("64px-SpaceInvadersLaserDepiction");
            shotmanager = new shotmanager(shottexture, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds);

            enemy = new EnemyManger(alienship, graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds, shotmanager);
```

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us which code line makes problems.

Comment: Your code clearly shows an EnemyManger class getting the instantiated instance of shotmanager. However, the Enemy class itself takes an instance (I'm guessing that's the null one?) of that class. Could EnemyManger not be passing it correctly? That code doesn't seem to be included.

Comment: What you tell us is not possible. If you call a method by passing a non-null object, then this method will see the object in any case. (I assume that multithreading is not involved here.)

Comment: @ Olivier Jacot shotmanager.fireenemyshot(pos);

Comment: Side note: I've removed story of your life and swearing from the post. Please for future post avoid text unrelated to the problem and instead make samples as short as possible. Wall of code is generally hard to deal with and may be considered as lack of effort on your part.

Comment: ehh Im a new guy here

Comment: This could be causing a problem: `public shotmanager shotmanager;` Make the `shotmanager` _class_ uppercase to avoid confusion, like this :`public Shotmanager shotmanager;`. Also, what's the _exact_ error, and what line are you receiving it on.

Comment: I dont think this is the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void fireenemyshot(Vector2 shotposition)    
{
    var inflatebounds = bounds;
    vec = shotposition;

    inflatebounds.Inflate(10, 10);
    // CULPRIT HERE
    shot.Velocity = new Vector2(0, 1);

    shotgroup.Add(shot);

    // THIS IS DONE TOO LATE.
    shot = new Shot(shottexture, shotposition, inflatebounds);
}
```

The problem is that you are attempting to set the `Velocity` on `shot`, but you have never instantiated it before here. You are instantiating it after you are attempting to use.

**EDIT - FYI**  <strike>The `pos` that you are passing into this method from `Enemy` is also never set. It's a struct so it should be initialized, however, you are never giving it a value.</strike>  Nevermind, I saw where it gets set.

Comment: same error, I tried that. what do you mean by "The pos that you are passing into this method from Enemy is also never set. It's a struct so it should be initialized, however, you are never giving it a value."

Comment: @user3446753 Did you attempt to correct the main issue I pointed out and not the FYI?

Comment: Yeah I did. placed the shot object above the velocity line

Comment: What I mentioned is the only thing I can come up with based on the information provided. Ignore my response about `pos`. I saw where it was getting set. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Well, I found the bug, how stupid of me. I was generating a class object, prior to its constructor, hence I keep getting the null error.

Comment: @user3446753, glad you found your error. JSYK, it probably isn't the best idea to use something like `public shotmanager shotmanager;`. Instead, capitalize the `Shotmanager` class to avoid confusion later on. Also, you code will be easier to follow.